# How to choice CNN architecture for stitching images

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, image-processing

I decided to start learning neural networks by creating a bot for the game. One of the intermediate steps is to create a global map from a series of inaccurate overlapping sub-maps. This task can be solved using OpenCV, but this solution will be too limited and sensitive (in the future I intend to complicate the task and work directly with the map image, instead of binary masks).

I've tried the following options:

- predict the position of a new map area within the global map. (as a probability distribution)
- predict the new state of the global map from the old and new minimap.

I've tried a lot of options formulation of the problem of network architecture, including the idea of conjoined networks, but nothing gave any relevant results.

Some articles about solving similar problems:

- [Automatic Field-of-View Expansion using Deep Features and Image Stitching](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050918315278)
- [JigsawNet: Shredded Image Reassembly using Convolutional Neural Network and Loop-based Composition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04137)
- [Robust Cylindrical Panorama Stitching for Low-Texture Scenes Based on Image Alignment Using Deep Learning and Iterative Optimization](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/19/23/5310/htm)

Here is an example of one of the options statement of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you please put your main question in the title?

Comment: @nbro, thank you for your feedback! Is it better now?